# clGetProgramBuildInfo does not print build log

Tags: c, linux, parallel-processing, opencl, gpgpu

I have written a code in OpenCL. There is an error while building the kernel program. The error code is -11. I tried printing the BUILD LOG but it does not print a proper log but instead it generates some random variables. Here is that part

```
//these are variable declarations
cl_device_id* devices;
cl_program kernelprgrm;
size_t size;
//these varaibles have already been assigned properly

//main code
clGetProgramBuildInfo(kernelprgrm,devices[i], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ,0,NULL,&size);
char *buildlog=(char*)malloc(size);
clGetProgramBuildInfo(kernelprgrm,devices[i], CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG ,size,buildlog,NULL);
printf("\n\nBuildlog:   %s\n\n",buildlog);
```

It gives the following output :-

```
Buildlog:   ���0
```

Please help me in getting a proper build log. Thanks

Comment: I already have. Uptil the buildlog everything works perfectly fine. The platforms are getting listed. I have built the context,commandqueue. Everything else works but there is an error with the kernel code which I am trying to find out using the buildlog but it is not giving me the exact error. @buttiful-buttefly

Comment: Have you checked the error codes returned by `clGetProgramBuildInfo`?

Comment: Ok I am updating the question and giving the entire code as well as output.

Comment: Yes. it returns -11 @jprice

Comment: I am also running a second program for which it returns -1 but getting the same buildlog

Comment: Can you try first checking the  `CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_STATUS`?

Comment: I looked up on the internet and found this code which gives the buildlog: `size_t len;
       char buffer[2048];
       printf("Error: Failed to build program executable!\n");
       clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, sizeof(buffer), 
       buffer, &len);

       printf("%s\n", buffer);`  Why wont my original code work? Any explanation?

Comment: Try verifying the size you're getting back from the first call, `size`.

Comment: Sorted it out. But it returns an empty string meaning CL_BUILD_NONE. Although my program runs successfully, what couold it mean?

Comment: This happened to me because I had a use-after-free error. I'm fairly certain something similar was at play here. The ���0 string is likely what free() has written to the memory to mark it as free.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this code on my machine and it works ok:

```
size_t len = 0;
cl_int ret = CL_SUCCESS;
ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, 0, NULL, &len);
char *buffer = calloc(len, sizeof(char));
ret = clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG, len, buffer, NULL);
```

As soon as it looks pretty much like your code, there are 2 differences, which may produce error:

- Check return codes
- Check index of device in array. May be you want to get log from wrong device.

Comment: Sorted it out. But it returns an empty string meaning `CL_BUILD_NONE`. Although my program runs successfully, what couold it mean?

Comment: Does it give you empty log after successful build?

Comment: Personally, I don't see any problem in empty log, if build is ok. Typical behaviour for any compiler (unless in verbose mode).