# Matrix multiplication returning incorrect result OpenCL

Tags: matrix, opencl

The following code is supposed to carry out matrix-matrix multiplication. Using OpenCL. When executing the code the resulting matrix C is filled with zeros. This is incorrect as I am multiplying two diagonal matrices with non-zero diagonal entries.

```
/*
Taken from http://gpgpu-computing4.blogspot.com/2009/09/matrix-multiplication-2-opencl.html

We have made some modifications, but need to understand what is going on.
*/

// Multiply two matrices A * B = C

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <CL\cl.h>
#include"OpenCLUtils.h"

/* WA : Width of A, HA : Width of A etc*/

#define WA 1024
#define HA 1024
#define WB 1024
#define LOCAL_WORK_SIZE 16
#define HB WA
#define WC WB
#define HC HA


void identityMultipliedByCoeff(float* data, int width, float coeff)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <width*width; ++i)
    {
        data[i] = 0.0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
    {
        data[i*width + i] = 1.0*coeff;
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    // set seed for rand()
    srand(2006);

    // 1. allocate host memory for matrices A and B
    unsigned int size_A = WA * HA;
    unsigned int mem_size_A = sizeof(float) * size_A;
    float* h_A = (float*)malloc(mem_size_A);

    unsigned int size_B = WB * HB;
    unsigned int mem_size_B = sizeof(float) * size_B;
    float* h_B = (float*)malloc(mem_size_B);

    // 2. initialize host memory
    identityMultipliedByCoeff(h_A, WA, 12.0);
    identityMultipliedByCoeff(h_B, WB, -9.0);

    // 4. allocate host memory for the result C
    unsigned int size_C = WC * HC;
    unsigned int mem_size_C = sizeof(float) * size_C;
    float* h_C = (float*)malloc(mem_size_C);

    // 5. Initialize OpenCL
    // OpenCL specific variables
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_context clGPUContext;
    cl_command_queue clCommandQue;
    cl_program clProgram;
    cl_kernel clKernel;

    size_t dataBytes;
    size_t kernelLength;
    cl_int errcode;

    // OpenCL device memory for matrices
    cl_mem d_A;
    cl_mem d_B;
    cl_mem d_C;

    /*****************************************/
    /* Initialize OpenCL */
    /*****************************************/
    /* Create a device and context */
    device = create_device();
    clGPUContext = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &errcode);
    if (errcode < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create a context");
        exit(1);
    }

    // get the list of GPU devices associated 
    // with context
    errcode = clGetContextInfo(clGPUContext,
        CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, 0, NULL,
        &dataBytes);
    cl_device_id *clDevices = (cl_device_id *)
        malloc(dataBytes);
    errcode |= clGetContextInfo(clGPUContext,
        CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES, dataBytes,
        clDevices, NULL);




    //Create a command-queue
    clCommandQue = clCreateCommandQueue(clGPUContext,clDevices[0], 0, &errcode);

    // Setup device memory
    /* We are passing the host memory as an argument. This is where
        the device memory obtains the data from the host memory. */
    d_C = clCreateBuffer(clGPUContext,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,mem_size_C, NULL, &errcode);
    d_A = clCreateBuffer(clGPUContext,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,mem_size_A, h_A, &errcode);
    d_B = clCreateBuffer(clGPUContext,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR,mem_size_B, h_B, &errcode);

    // 6. Load and build OpenCL kernel

    // Open the .cl file and load it
    // into a char* buffer
    FILE* fp = fopen("MatMul.cl", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    const size_t lSize = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    unsigned char* buffer;
    buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(lSize);
    fread(buffer, 1, lSize, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    cl_int status;
    clProgram = clCreateProgramWithBinary(clGPUContext,
        1, (const cl_device_id *)clDevices,
        &lSize, (const unsigned char**)&buffer,
        &status, &errcode);

    errcode = clBuildProgram(clProgram, 0, NULL, NULL,
        NULL, NULL);

    errcode = clBuildProgram(clProgram, 0,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    clKernel = clCreateKernel(clProgram,
        "matrixMul", &errcode);

    // 7. Launch OpenCL kernel
    size_t localWorkSize[2], globalWorkSize[2];

    int wA = WA;
    int wC = WC;

    /* Set the arguments for the kernel. */
    errcode = clSetKernelArg(clKernel, 0,sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&d_C);
    errcode |= clSetKernelArg(clKernel, 1,sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&d_A);
    errcode |= clSetKernelArg(clKernel, 2,sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&d_B);
    errcode |= clSetKernelArg(clKernel, 3,sizeof(int), (void *)&wA);
    errcode |= clSetKernelArg(clKernel, 4,sizeof(int), (void *)&wC);

    /* Rember that in OpenCL we need to express the
        globalWorkSize in terms of the total number of threads.
        The underlying OpenCL API will look at the 
        globalWorkSize and divide by the localWorkSize to 
        arrive at a 64 by 64 NDRange of 16 by 16 work groups. */

    localWorkSize[0] = LOCAL_WORK_SIZE;
    localWorkSize[1] = LOCAL_WORK_SIZE;
    globalWorkSize[0] = WA;
    globalWorkSize[1] = HA;

    errcode = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(clCommandQue,clKernel, 2, NULL, globalWorkSize,localWorkSize, 0, NULL, NULL);


    //
    // The calculation has now been carried out
    //


    // 8. Retrieve result from device
    errcode = clEnqueueReadBuffer(clCommandQue,
        d_C, CL_TRUE, 0, mem_size_C,
        h_C, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // We must check the result

    for (int i = 0; i < WA; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < WA; j++)
        {
            float prod = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < WA;k++)
            {
                prod += h_A[i*WA + k] * h_B[k*WA + j];
            }
            if (fabs(h_C[i*WA+j] - prod) > 0.01)
            {
                printf("The indices where the comparison failed, i = %d, j = %d\n", i,j);
                printf("C[i*WA+j] should equal %f\n", prod);
                printf("C[i*WA+j] = %f\n", h_C[i*WA + j]);
                perror("The matrix check has failed");
                exit(1);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    printf("The matrix check has been successfull!\n");


    // 10. clean up memory
    free(h_A);
    free(h_B);
    free(h_C);

    clReleaseMemObject(d_A);
    clReleaseMemObject(d_C);
    clReleaseMemObject(d_B);

    free(clDevices);
    clReleaseContext(clGPUContext);
    clReleaseKernel(clKernel);
    clReleaseProgram(clProgram);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(clCommandQue);

}
```

The .cpp file for the header file OpenCLUtils.h is given as:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<CL\cl.h>

cl_device_id create_device() {

    cl_platform_id* platforms;
    cl_uint num_platforms,num_devices;
    cl_device_id* devices;
    char platform_name_data[50];
    char name_data[50];
    cl_int i,err,platformchoice;

    platformchoice =1;

    /* Find out how many platforms there are */
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, NULL, &num_platforms);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't identify a platform");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Reserve memory for platforms*/
    platforms = (cl_platform_id*)malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id)*num_platforms);

    /* Obtain the available platforms and store them in the array platforms */
    clGetPlatformIDs(num_platforms, platforms, NULL);

    /* We want to know the names of the platforms.
    This will the inform us and lead to a
    cannonical choice for 'platformchoice'.*/

    for (i = 0; i < num_platforms; i++)
    {
        err = clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, sizeof(platform_name_data), platform_name_data, NULL);
        if (err < 0)
        {
            perror("Unable to obtain information about platform");
        }
        printf("%s\n", platform_name_data);
    }

    printf("\nSearching %s for available devices...\n", platform_name_data);

    /* Obtain the number of GPUS available on this platform */
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[platformchoice], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 0, NULL, &num_devices);
    if (err == CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) 
    {
        perror("No GPU devices available");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Could not access any devices. Not as a result of the device not being found. Debug for error code");
        exit(1);
    }
    /* Reserve memory for devices */
    devices = (cl_device_id*)malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id)*num_devices);

    /* Populate devices with devices compatible with the chosen platform */
    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[platformchoice], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, num_devices, devices, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < num_devices; i++)
    {
        err = clGetDeviceInfo(devices[i], CL_DEVICE_NAME, sizeof(name_data), name_data, NULL);
        if (err < 0)
        {
            perror("Unable to obtain information about device");
        }
        printf("%s\n", name_data);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return devices[0];
}
```

I am using an AMD GPU. It is an R9 380. The above "utility" code allows me to select the platform and then choose a device that has supports that platform. Regardless whether I choose intel's or AMD's platform, the result is the same.

The matrix multiplication kernel is given in

http://gpgpu-computing4.blogspot.com/2009/10/matrix-multiplication-3-opencl.html

The print screen from my VisualStudio debugger is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlyvk.png)

it is showing that status is equal to -42 which means CL_INVALID_BINARY according to https://streamhpc.com/blog/2013-04-28/opencl-error-codes/

EDIT:

I tried this

```
...
// 6. Load and build OpenCL kernel

// Obtain size of source file
FILE* fp = fopen("MatMul.cl", "r");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
const size_t lSize = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

// Read file content into buffer
unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(lSize+1);
buffer[lSize] = '\0';
fread(buffer, sizeof(char), lSize, fp);
fclose(fp);

//create program from buffer
clProgram = clCreateProgramWithSource(clGPUContext,1,(const char**)&buffer,&lSize, &errcode);

errcode = clBuildProgram(clProgram, 1,&device, NULL,NULL, NULL);

clKernel = clCreateKernel(clProgram,
    "matrixMul", &errcode);
...
```

But get the error code -11 now CL_BUILD_PROGRAM _FAILURE

FINAL EDIT:

I GOT IT TO WORK

Here is the corrected kernel

```
/* Matrix multiplication: C = A * B.
 * Device code.
 */

// Thread block size
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Matrix multiplication on the device: C = A * B
//! wA is A's width and wB is B's width
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
__kernel void
matrixMul(__global float* C, 
          __global float* A, 
          __global float* B, int wA, int wB)
{

    float Csub=0;   <<<<<<< THIS WAS MISSING IN THE BLOG

    // Block index
    int bx = get_group_id(0);
    int by = get_group_id(1);

    // Thread index
    int tx = get_local_id(0);
    int ty = get_local_id(1);

    // Index of the first sub-matrix of A processed 
    // by the block
    int aBegin = wA * BLOCK_SIZE * by;

    // Index of the last sub-matrix of A processed 
    // by the block
    int aEnd   = aBegin + wA - 1;

    // Step size used to iterate through the 
    // sub-matrices of A
    int aStep  = BLOCK_SIZE;

    // Index of the first sub-matrix of B processed 
    // by the block
    int bBegin = BLOCK_SIZE * bx;

    // Step size used to iterate through the 
    // sub-matrices of B
    int bStep  = BLOCK_SIZE * wB;

    // Loop over all the sub-matrices of A and B
    // required to compute the block sub-matrix
    for (int a = aBegin, b = bBegin;
             a <= aEnd;
             a += aStep, b += bStep) 
    {

        // Declaration of the local memory array As 
        // used to store the sub-matrix of A
        __local float As[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

        // Declaration of the local memory array Bs 
        // used to store the sub-matrix of B
        __local float Bs[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

        // Load the matrices from global memory
        // to local memory; each thread loads
        // one element of each matrix
        As[ty][tx] = A[a + wA * ty + tx];
        Bs[ty][tx] = B[b + wB * ty + tx];

        // Synchronize to make sure the matrices 
        // are loaded
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

        // Multiply the two matrices together;
        // each thread computes one element
        // of the block sub-matrix
        for (int k = 0; k < BLOCK_SIZE; ++k)
            Csub += As[ty][k] * Bs[k][tx];

        // Synchronize to make sure that the preceding
        // computation is done before loading two new
        // sub-matrices of A and B in the next iteration
        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    }

    // Write the block sub-matrix to device memory;
    // each thread writes one element
    int c = wB * BLOCK_SIZE * by + BLOCK_SIZE * bx;
    C[c + wB * ty + tx] = Csub;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error lies in this line:

```
 d_C = clCreateBuffer(clGPUContext,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,mem_size_A, NULL, &errcode);
```

The third argument should be `mem_size_C`

Edit: Also, for performance sake I recommend you use clEnqueueWriteBuffer for copying over matrices A and B. Further reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832963/what-is-the-difference-between-creating-a-buffer-object-with-clcreatebuffer-cl)

Comment: I tried that and it did not solve the problem. I updated the code as the code used to identify whether or not the code was a success was a bit off too.

Comment: Okay. Do you mind adding printf statements to your kernel code to see if A and B are copied onto the device correctly? I will peruse your code some more in the meantime.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks :)

Comment: Another sanity check that helps is checking the value of the errcode **every** time you call a cl function.
In fact, you should probably do that before trying anything else

Comment: That's a good point. Thus far it seems like there are no errors (the ones that have been checked).

Comment: I used the answer to this question to attempt to get a build log https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157337/clgetprogrambuildinfo-does-not-print-build-log  It is just printing "little 2's". As in, the power of 2. Printf in the kernel code does nothing. Although I don't think this is what you meant.

Comment: you mind editing your code above to show where you put it? Also, does this mean clBuildProgram is returning -11?

Comment: It seems like its returning 0. But on checking my debugging window clCreateProgramWithBinary is returning -42

Comment: Ok. I think I know where your problem is: 
The way your code is written requires the kernel to be compiled separately, and during runtime your main programme will read the binary (this is called offline compiling). You are giving your main programme the uncompiled file, MatMul.cl

Comment: Instead, you need to find out the name of the binary file and switch MatMul.cl with it here: `FILE* fp = fopen("MatMul.cl", "r");`

Comment: Is there a way I can avoid doing this? By compiling from source? I have included what I have tried in an EDIT

Comment: I think you're in the right direction by doing an online compile instead. You should check your build log to see why you got a -11.

Comment: It is telling me that "the source file is not valid UTF-8". But my file is, according to Nodepad. Changing "r" to "rb" removes this issue. BUT the C is still a zero matrix

Comment: I got it to work in the end. There was an error surrounding the kernel in the build log that I missed. I have included the final version in the description. Thanks for your help. I have learned a lot about OpenCL today because of you! Thanks!